# cmd line parameter string.Contains behaving differently from hardcoded parameter

Tags: go

I'm looking to get some clarification on why these two strings.Contains() calls behave differently.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "os"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    hardcoded := "col1,col2,col3\nval1,val2,val3"
    if strings.Contains(hardcoded, "\n") == false {
        panic(errors.New("The hardcoded string should contain a new line"))
    }
    fmt.Println("New line found in hardcoded string")

    if len(os.Args) == 2 {
        fmt.Println("parameter:", os.Args[1])
        if strings.Contains(os.Args[1], "\n") == false {
            panic(errors.New("The parameter string should contain a new line."))
        }
        fmt.Println("New line found in parameter string")
    }

}
```

If I run this with

```
go run input-tester.go col1,col2,col3\\nval1,val2,val3
```

I get the following

```
New line found in hardcoded string
parameter: col1,col2,col3\nval1,val2,val3
panic: The parameter string should contain a new line.

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x497100, 0xc42000e310)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
main.main()
    /home/user/Desktop/input-tester.go:21 +0x343
exit status 2
```

I can see that the string printed out is the same format as the string that is hardcoded yet the string.Contains() doesn't find the "\n".

I'm guessing this is an oversight on my part. Can anyone explain what I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: It works if we use ` \n ` for command-line arguments

Comment: Oh dear - seems one of the previous respondents deleted their comment, then downvoted this question, then accessed my profile and downvoted all my previous questions :D Poor John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves differently because in hardcoded \n is considered as new line parameter.
And in command line arguments , argument type is string, where given condition is for "\n" which is considered as new line parameter.
Simply ` \n   compaires with two consecutive characters "\" and "n" not with "\n" a new line character.

So for command line arguments use,

```
if strings.Contains(os.Args[1], `\n`) == false {
        panic(errors.New("The parameter string should contain a new line."))
    }
```

Reference : https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote. The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the string may contain newlines.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for that.